# Select some rows from a XML file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have an XML that i want to export some rows, base in attribute 1 content.

My File is like that:

```
<Root>
  <First_Level_Node>
    <Element_Name>
      <attribute1>1</attribute1>
      <attribute2>2</attribute2>
      <attribute3>3</attribute3>
      <attribute4>4</attribute4>
      <attribute5>5</attribute5>
      <attribute6>6</attribute6>
    </Element_Name>
    <Element_Name>
      <attribute1>41</attribute1>
      <attribute2></attribute2>
      <attribute3>NO</attribute3>
      <attribute4>42</attribute4>
      <attribute5>random value</attribute5>
      <attribute6>18th Jun 2014  07:09:18 GMT</attribute6>
    </Element_Name>
    <Element_Name>
      <attribute1>42</attribute1>
      <attribute2></attribute2>
      <attribute3>NO</attribute3>
      <attribute4>42</attribute4>
      <attribute5>random</attribute5>
      <attribute6>23rd Jul 2014  02:47:10 GMT</attribute6>
    </Element_Name>
    <Element_Name>
      <attribute1>43</attribute1>
      <attribute2></attribute2>
      <attribute3>NO</attribute3>
      <attribute4>42</attribute4>
      <attribute5>random</attribute5>
      <attribute6>08th Nov 2014  23:53:31 GMT</attribute6>
    </Element_Name>
  </First_Level_Node>
</Root>
```

And based on the value of the attribute 1, I want to get all the rows from that element.
For example, I want attribute 1 = 42 or attribute 1 = 43, so the output will be like:

```
<Root>
  <First_Level_Node>
    <Element_Name>
      <attribute1>42</attribute1>
      <attribute2></attribute2>
      <attribute3>NO</attribute3>
      <attribute4>42</attribute4>
      <attribute5>random</attribute5>
      <attribute6>23rd Jul 2014  02:47:10 GMT</attribute6>
    </Element_Name>
    <Element_Name>
      <attribute1>43</attribute1>
      <attribute2></attribute2>
      <attribute3>NO</attribute3>
      <attribute4>42</attribute4>
      <attribute5>random</attribute5>
      <attribute6>08th Nov 2014  23:53:31 GMT</attribute6>
    </Element_Name>
  </First_Level_Node>
</Root>
```

I want to use Python for this.

I tried to use ElementTree, but was unsuccessful. That's what I tried so far

```
with open("output.xml", 'r') as f3:
        root = ET.parse(f3)

    tree=root.getroot()
    with open("list_xxx", 'r') as f2:
        for line in f2:
            line = line.rstrip()
            print (line)
            #get all subnet nodes containing certain ManagedElementId
            subnet_path = './/*[attribute1="{0}"]'
            subnet_path = subnet_path.format(line)
            for subnet in tree.findall(subnet_path):
                #reconstruct subnet node:
                parent = ET.Element(subnet.tag, attrib=subnet.attrib)
                #path to find all ManagedElement containing certain ManagedElementId
                content_path = ".//*[attribute1='{0}']".format(line)
                print (content_path)

                #append all ManagedElement found to the new subnet:
                for content in subnet.findall(content_path):
                    parent.append(content)
                #print new subnet:
                print (ET.tostring(parent))
```

And list xxx has the values of attribute 1 that I am looking for:

```
41
42
```

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far. Try reading this about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @eusoubrasileiro done, can you help me?

Comment: It's far easier to do it with the lxml library, if you can use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using lxml and xpath should make it much simpler:

```
from lxml import etree

dat = """[your xml snippet above]"""
doc = etree.fromstring(dat)

targets = doc.xpath('//Element_Name[not(attribute1="42" or attribute1="43")]')
#the xpath expression above selects all ElementName nodes which do NOT meet your requirements
for target in targets:
    target.getparent().remove(target) #once an unnecessary element is selected, you go up to the parent and remove the unnecessary element
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

Output is your desire output.

Comment: Worked! TY SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

You've already pre-selected the `Element_Name` elements which have the specified `attribute1` contents (41 and 42).  There is no need to re-select them a second time, which is causing the entire `Element_Name` element to be returned by `findall()`.

You just need to select the child `attribute1` elements at that point.

Therefore, if you change

```
content_path = ".//*[attribute1='{0}']".format(line)
```

to

```
 content_path = "attribute1"
```

your program will print:

```
41
attribute1
b'<Element_Name><attribute1>41</attribute1>\n      </Element_Name>'
42
attribute1
b'<Element_Name><attribute1>42</attribute1>\n      </Element_Name>'
```